# Developer-ID app validation removed in XCode 8.3 Beta 3 and Beta 4 - publishing outside of the Mac App Store still possible?

Tags: xcode, macos

Trying to validate an archive on XCode 8.3 Beta 3 or 4, the Developer-ID option is no longer there - it automatically tried to validate it for Mac App. Store.
The project works fine on the first XCode Beta.

I raised a bug report and got this response from Apple: "Developer ID app validation was removed."

I've looked around and can't find any announcement of this.

My question: does anyone know if this means that Apple is removing our right to publish outside of the Mac App store?

(I'm sure I'm not the only one who would be negatively affected by this - I've put a lot of work into getting a solution working outside of the store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer ID distribution is fully supported. Most of what the Developer ID validation function did was verify that you weren't using entitlements that you couldn't use with Developer ID. In Xcode 8.3, this functionality has been folded into the code signing and provisioning checks that are performed when you choose to export your app for Developer ID distribution.

Comment: Ah thanks! - so, no it's no longer necessary to Validate, and when you export you're still given the Developer-ID option? - have I understood?

Comment: apologies for not accepting your answer sooner - I was diverted to other things and have only just had a chance to test this out. Thanks!